# Creating lambda Function to Trigger Codebuild Project using Nodejs with help api request

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-codepipeline, aws-codebuild, aws-codecommit

how can I write node.js lambda function to call code build function to auto rebuild the project without any manual operations

Answer (score 3):

For the lambda You can use aws sdk to do that, example :

```
const AWS = require("aws-sdk");
const codebuildSDK = new AWS.CodeBuild();
const build = {
   projectName: "MyProjectBuild"
};
result = await codebuildSDK.startBuild(params).promise();
```

but if you want, you can directly use Cloud watch event to run directly a Codebuild as a target https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/events/CloudWatch-Events-tutorial-codebuild.html